# Mongock spring-boot delay bean creation until Mongock is done

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mongock

With liquibase and Spring Boot I can do `@DependsOn("liquibase")` to wait when I have a `@Bean` creating method. This lets me create beans that depend on initialization data.

How do I do this in mongock?

I saw this question but I need to order the bean creation in the context, not force the context to wait on the mongock init to happen before being complete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to do this we can't use the annotation configuration, we need to use the Mongock initializing bean and create it in a `@Bean`, name it, and then we can use `DependsOn('mongock')` for dependent beans:

Note that this is Kotlin...

```
@Configuration
class MongockConfiguration {
    @Bean("mongock")
    fun mongockInitializingBeanRunner(
        mongoTemplate: MongoTemplate,
        applicationContext: ApplicationContext
    ): MongockInitializingBeanRunner {
        return MongockSpringboot.builder()
            .setDriver(SpringDataMongoV4Driver.withDefaultLock(mongoTemplate))
            .addMigrationScanPackage("come.package.changelog")
            .setSpringContext(applicationContext)
            .buildInitializingBeanRunner();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for asking(and answering). Your workaround seems to work fine. Anyway, we are adding it to our roadmap for our next major release. Thanks.